# Pandas multi-index count occurrences

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a Pandas DataFrame with MultiIndexing

```
(Index col 1) (Index col 2) (Data col 1) ....
A               a            word1
                a            word2
                b            word3
B               a            word4
                c            word5
```

Now I want to count all the rows that have the same combination of Index column 1 and Index column 2. I've tried df.value_counts(), which gives the error 'DataFrame does not have a method value_counts(). If I use df.count(), I can only count for level=0 or level=1, not both at the same time (the level parameter does not seem to accept a list, even though I often see that used on stackoverflow).

Desired output:
A a 2
A b 1
.. etc

[EDIT]: OK so @EdChum's comment solved the problem, but I am still wondering why the other stuff did not work? Specifically: why does value_counts not seem to be defined while it is part of the latest Pandas? Does this have anything to do with me using a Jupyter Notebook? Or do these things change a lot between Pandas versions?

Comment: try `df.groupby(level=[0,1]).size()`

Comment: @EdChum that did it, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can `groupby` on the indices of interest and call `size` to return a count of the unique values:

```
In [4]:
df.groupby(level=[0,1]).size()

Out[4]:
(Index col 1)  (Index col 2)
A              a                2
               b                1
B              a                1
               c                1
dtype: int64
```

`value_counts` is a series method, it's not defined for a df which is why it didn't work

Comment: Ipython/Jupyter? or Spyder?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi what is your comment regarding?

Comment: In[4] and Out[4] notation.

Comment: `ipython/jupyter`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the index.get_level_values to combine an index level with another column

```
 grouped = df.groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0),'Num']).size()
```