# Count Y values for each X value - MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have this kind of df...

```
          Modules
X     Y   
1    1          A
     2          B
     45         C
2    13         A
     12         B
3    18         A
     16         B
     15         D
```

I would like to count the number of Y values for each X value and add this as a column, like this:

```
          Modules  Count 
X     Y   
1    1          A      3
     2          B      3
     45         C      3
2    13         A      2
     12         B      2
3    18         A      3
     16         B      3
     15         D      3
```

For the moment I've tried :

```py
df['Count']=df.index.get_level_values(0).value_counts()
```

which gives me a list of NaN, then I tried :

```py
df['Count']=df.index.value_counts()
```

which obviously give me a list of 1.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Please use `df.to_dict()` and post the result ehre so we have copy/pasteable data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas multi-index count occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183331/pandas-multi-index-count-occurrences)

Comment: @AmitGupta No because I just need the number of occurences of X, whatever the Y value.

Comment: @Andreas {'X': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 3, 7: 3},
 'Y': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 45, 3: 13, 4: 12, 5: 18, 6: 16, 7: 15},
 'Modules': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'A', 4: 'B', 5: 'A', 6: 'B', 7: 'D'}} Is it what you wanted? Sorry I'm new to StackOverflow

Comment: Using the Panda's question linked, instead of grouping by the 2 columns, just group by the one that you are interested in. That should get you the results you are looking for correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can groupby and count the entries per group, since you want a series returned with the same length as the original, you can use `.transform()` which will do exactly that:

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby(['X'])['Modules'].transform('count')


   X   Y Modules  Count
0  1   1       A      3
1  1   1       B      3
2  1  45       C      3
3  2  13       A      2
4  2  12       B      2
5  3  18       A      3
6  3  16       B      3
7  3  15       D      3
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. How can I make my example copy/pasteable please? I'm pretty new to StackOverflow sorry...

Comment: @Mop you can use: `df.to_dict()` which returns a dictionary of your data. we can use this to recreate your dataframe. If you dont want to post the full data you can limit the rows like this: `df.iloc[:10].to_dict()` to the first 10 rows of your data.

Comment: {'X': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 3, 7: 3},
 'Y': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 45, 3: 13, 4: 12, 5: 18, 6: 16, 7: 15},
 'Modules': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'A', 4: 'B', 5: 'A', 6: 'B', 7: 'D'}}

Comment: Is it what you wanted?

Comment: @Mop, yes I adjusted my code.

Comment: Damn it's working, thank you a lot dude ! And sorry for not posting df.to_dict(). How I should do next time? Put it at the end of the post? Again thank you a lot!

Comment: @Mop you can provide the data directly like this: `df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ..., 'Y': ...})` directly at the start in addition to the data you posted to also "see" it. If my answer was helpful, please consider upvoting and accepting the answer. It helpf future readers and I get a few points. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df.groupby(level=[0,1]).size()
```

you can give any name to the column when assign it.

Comment: I tried it but it just give a list of 1. Something I forget to say is sometimes in my dataset, the Y values are not the same for a same X. Sorry I'm new to StackOverflow